# Getting data for notifications in a OOP way with C#

Tags: c#, email, oop

We have a system in which a small parts of it is to send out notifications via e-mail, we call a method that gets a list of type Person containing the data we need (e-mail addresses) for sending out notifications like this:

```
List<person> peopleToNotify= GetPRNotificationData();
string recipients = peopleToNotify.ForEach(p=>concat+=p.email+";");
try{Mail m = new Mail(body, message, recipients).Send();}catch{}
```

My fellow developer recommends we create a stored procedure for the purposes of returning an already concatenated list of e-mails to avoid the recipients variable altogether.

My argument for that is, how much of an improvement does that represent in terms of memory/speed compared to the current implementation? Also, if they decide to send notifications as text messages or something else, that information is still relevant to the user, so re-usability is a must in a world of OOP, otherwise we would have to create ANOTHER stored procedure to return whatever we would need, I say NO to that, instead we return a list of type Person that contains the relevant data, if phone numbers, then we add that to the person class, etc.

From an architecture standpoint no matter what the notification medium is, we are still getting "NotificationData", this is abstract enough to accommodate whatever change they want.

any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a question regarding this in the Software Engineering SE: [_“Never do in code what you can get the SQL server to do well for you” - Is this a recipe for a bad design?_](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this)

Comment: It seems a very small detail then discussion might be pretty academic but...Where did you put your logic? Is everything in SQL? Do you already have logic in place with code? Not to mention that format depends on what code requires. Does it sql do it better in any way?

Comment: This code is part of a business layer (it's own assembly), this is within a method that Submits something and people have to get notified right afterwards, so this is the last bit in the method. By the way, thank you for your time.